# Uninnstall ubuntu, install Windows 8

Tags: windows, live-usb

## Windows 8

I really want to replace ubuntu with windows 8. I cant figure out how :O Can someone please help me?

And yes, i have bought windows 8. I have the ios file, but I also need help to create a bootable Usb stick.

Comment: It seems this is about how to create a Windows 8 install USB on Ubuntu (starting with an image file). I believe Windows installation media generally cannot be created in exactly the same was as installation media for Ubuntu and many other operating systems. I think Microsoft (and other sources) give instructions for doing it *on Windows.* If you have instructions you consider reliable for that--perhaps from Microsoft, provided with Windows 8--and you added them to your question or linked to them, *then* this question would be about a specific task on Ubuntu and could be kept open and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Windows 8 CD, then just fire it up. Windows should be able to detect the hard drive partitions as normal which you can then choose the Windows partition and install your Windows 8 CD.